# How to .gitignore "public/images/" folder in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I've referred to many related posts here and none of them work -- my `public/images` folder just not greying out like my `node_modules` folder does in my VS Code. The following is my folder structure:

```
project-folder
  |--.gitignore
  |--node_modules
  |--public
  |----images
```

So my `.gitignore` file is at the same level at my public folder. I saw the `node_modules` is being ignored (and greyed out) in the `.gitignore` file like this:

`node_modules/`

So I tried:

`public/images/`

but no luck. I also tried all of the following but none turn the `images` folder into grey:

```
 1. /public/images/
 2. /public/images
 3. public/images
 4. public/images/
 5. images
 6. images/
```

I also tried creating another `.gitignore` file under the `public` folder and follow the same way my `node_modules` is being ignored but still not working: `images/`. I heard that the `git rm --cached` may sometimes remove files from file system, so I dare not try it. Can someone give me a better advice for this? Thanks!

Comment: You need to remove the files from the cache first as it has already been added to the repo. Or else just adding your directory to gitignore won’t work as it only works for for file that hasn’t been added.

Comment: Did you tried `public/`

Comment: @chiragsoni : No, I want to keep my `public` folder. It some other folders and files that I need, e.g. `*.js`, `*.css` etc. I just want to ignore `images` folder.

Comment: try with `/images` and let me know

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: If your `.gitignore` is at `public` folder then you can use `/images/` to ignore the `public/images` folder. Also make sure you don't have `.gitignore` inside `public/images` folder.

Comment: @AntonioOoi Did it worked??

Comment: @HarishST : Still the same not working.
@chiragsoni : Already answered you earlier, not working.
@LalitaCode : `git rm -r --cached images` works perfectly by running the command at the `public` directory level. No files have been removed from the file system, only the git index. Thanks!

Comment: Create a `.gitignore` file inside image folder and add `*` to it. Check whether this works or not

Comment: @1615903 : Yes, but in the beginners' perspective like me, they may not even know that the files or folders that previously tracked have to be **"forgotten** and they just want the  git not to track the files or folders by turning them into **grey color** in VS Code. I feel that it's good to keep this question so that people who are at the same knowledge level as me can find the question right for them. I appreciate your offer for the same answer though. Thank you.

Comment: Marking a question as duplicate does not remove it, it just places a banner on top pointing future visitors to the other question.

Comment: Fine, then I'll answer 'Yes' to your question, but in my opinion, unless the question title does not serve different perspective and almost identical, otherwise it's good to leave the diverse perspectives of questions here and lead the solution seekers to the best, clearest, and most insightful answer, else similar "duplications" may just come back again and again due to different perspectives and scenarios. Also, it's unwise to change the question to almost close to the answer -- this is expert's perspective, not beginners' perspective. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved the problem by issuing `git rm -r --cached images` at the `public` directory level. **No physical files have been removed from the file system** except the `git index`. The working pattern in the `.gitignore` file at the project root folder is:

`public/images/`

After issuing the above command, my `images` folder under `public` has been greyed out in my VS Code. Thanks to **@LalitaCode** for giving me the courage to try `git rm --cached` and thanks to those who were trying to help as well!